# cakephp auth component: password hashing problem

Tags: cakephp, hash, authentication

I am using the auth component straight out the box. When a user enters their password it hashes it using the salt in my core.php file. Is there a way to manually hash a variable using this same method? Because I want the user to have the ability to change their password so say they enter the new password and I store it in $newPassword, how would I hash this in the same way to then insert into the database?

Thanks

Geoff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AuthComponent::password()

http://book.cakephp.org/view/247/AuthComponent-Methods

Answer (score 0):

on your change password just pass the username as a hidden field and cake will hash it auto, you can also check the method above or Security::hash() to do it manually.